# C# VAMemory read float returns 0

Tags: c#, memory

I've been trying to make a Trainer for a game as a sort of learning project in visual studio but i'm completely stuck.

What i want to do is read the Y position value in the game and put the returned float value in a textbox whenever the `btnConnect` button is clicked so it shows the player's Y position, but whatever i try i always get "0" back in the `valPosY` textbox instead of the "2992.065918" i see in Cheat Engine.

The code:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("QUBE-Win64-Shipping");

        if (processes.Length > 0)
        {
            btnConnect.Text = "Connected!";
            Process GameProcess = processes[0];

            VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("QUBE-Win64-Shipping");

            IntPtr Base = GameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress + 0x0290B008;
            Base = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base), 0x58);
            Base = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base), 0x340);
            Base = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base), 0x18);
            Base = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base), 0x100);
            Base = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(Base), 0x198);
            float valY = vam.ReadFloat(Base);

            valPosY.Text = valY.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            btnConnect.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find a process named 'QUBE-Win64-Shipping'!", "Error Finding Process", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

If i close the game the if statement doesn't pass so that means it should be getting the correct process that i need.

[This is the pointer i got with Cheat Engine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCFzw.png)

I am also not getting any error or warning messages.
Please tell me if more info is needed, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple more hours of head scratching i realized i was indeed being dumb and had to change every `ReadInt32(Base)` to `ReadInt64(Base)`.